# Randomly drawing samples from matrix normal distribution in python

Tags: python, numpy, normal-distribution

Is there a way to randomly draw samples from the matrix normal distribution (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_normal_distribution#Drawing_values_from_the_distribution) using python? Numpy has functionality for drawing from the 1-D normal distribution and the multivariate normal distribution, but I can't find anything on the matrix normal distribution. Thanks.

Answer (score 7):

From the wikipedia page you link:

> The matrix normal is related to the multivariate normal distribution in the following way:
>
> [image: \mathbf{X} \sim \mathcal{MN}_{n\times p}(\mathbf{M}, \mathbf{U}, \mathbf{V}),]
>
> if and only if
>
> [image: \mathrm{vec}(\mathbf{X}) \sim \mathcal{N}_{np}(\mathrm{vec}(\mathbf{M}), \mathbf{V} \otimes \mathbf{U})]

Translated to numpy, that should be

```
numpy.random.multivariate_normal(M.ravel(), np.kron(V, U)).reshape(M.shape)
```

Comment: This is the correct answer. Though if the dimensions n and p are large, you might need to do something fancier to avoid long computation time.

Answer (score 1):

`numpy.random.normal()` could draw 2d matrix as long as you specify size like this：

```
numpy.random.normal(loc = mean, scale = standard deviation, size = (m,n))
```